# how to make partition in sql work. it gives error near (

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
WITH xyz 
AS
(
    SELECT  col1, col2, col3, col4,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4) as RowNumber
    FROM  table1
 )
```

tried to get the above code to work in microsoft SQL 2008 but it keeps giving syntax error near '('
cant figure out what is wrong

Comment: Is that your full code? You are missing the `select * from xyz` after the final closing parentheses

Comment: If that's the entire query, it should report incorrect syntax near `)`, rather than `(`. Typo in question, or there's more code to show? Also, it's rarely, if ever, correct for exactly the same columns to appear in both `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` - but hopefully that's just where you've anonymized the real query.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using that CTE right after this, so try adding a semicolon before `WITH` statement, like this :

```
;WITH xyz 
AS
(
    SELECT  col1, col2, col3, col4,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4) as RowNumber
    FROM  table1
)
```

When using a CTE, the previous statement must be closed with a semicolon. If you're not already doing it, Try adding `SELECT * FROM xyz` after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: That should almost always generate the specific error "Incorrect syntax near 'xyz'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.". I've been trying and failing to construct a query to precede this one that will produce the reported error message.